# Joining tables with Medoo (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I'm not too familiar with databases and I've run into a situation where I have to use a `join`.

`products` table:

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════╗
║ product_id ║   MPN   ║ manufacturer_id ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═════════════════╣
║         51 ║ GB40337 ║              11 ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════╝
```

`manufacturers` table:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════╗
║ manufacturer_id ║  name   ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════╣
║              11 ║ Griffin ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════╝
```

Now as I understand, it would require an **inner join** to get the manufacturer name? So I ran this query:

```
SELECT product.mpn, manufacturer.name
FROM product
INNER JOIN manufacturer
ON product.manufacturer_id=manufacturer.manufacturer_id;
```

and it returns the data correctly but now since I'm using `Medoo` I have to use its syntax which I can't quite get: http://medoo.in/api/select

How do I use medoo for the same query?

Comment: Did you try `// [><] == INNER JOIN` as described in the "Table Joining" part of the page you referred to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Medoo You can write your query like this.

read this https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-medoo-examples-use/

```
$db->select(
    'product', 
    array('[><]manufacturer' => array('product.manufacturer_id' => 'manufacturer.manufacturer_id')),
    array('product.mpn', 'manufacturer.name')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$database->select("product", [
            "[><]manufacturer" => ["manufacturer_id" => "manufacturer_id"]], [
            "product.mpn",
            "manufacturer.name"]);
```